# Exclude values from oracle partition

Tags: sql, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I want to use a Composite Range-List Partitioning in oracle.

Using a range is pretty clear to me. The tricky part is on the list partition and this is where i have the question.

Let's assume we have a column with continents. I want the list partition that to include all the continents that are **NOT** Europe. The problem here is that i cannot create a list partition including all other continents except of Europe, as at some point i might add new continents.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/part_admin.htm#i1006532)

> With list partitioning, there is no apparent sense of order between
>   partitions. You can also specify a **default partition** into which rows
>   that do not map to any other partition are mapped.

Based on above, you can create two partitions, one for Europe and another for others and set latter as default too.
This way you can have your data of Europe in one partition and anything other than europe goes to default partition.

**Here is an example**

```
CREATE TABLE sample_regional_sales
      (deptno number, item_no varchar2(20),
       txn_date date, txn_amount number, state varchar2(2))
  PARTITION BY RANGE (txn_date)
    SUBPARTITION BY LIST (state)
      (PARTITION q1_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-APR-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_1
         (SUBPARTITION q1_1999_northwest VALUES ('OR', 'WA'),
          SUBPARTITION q1_1999_southwest VALUES ('AZ', 'UT', 'NM'),
          SUBPARTITION q1_1999_northeast VALUES ('NY', 'VM', 'NJ'),
          SUBPARTITION q1_1999_southeast VALUES ('FL', 'GA'),
          SUBPARTITION q1_others VALUES (DEFAULT) TABLESPACE tbs_4
         ),
       PARTITION q2_1999 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('1-JUL-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_2
         (SUBPARTITION q2_1999_northwest VALUES ('OR', 'WA'),
          SUBPARTITION q2_1999_southwest VALUES ('AZ', 'UT', 'NM'),
          SUBPARTITION q2_1999_northeast VALUES ('NY', 'VM', 'NJ'),
          SUBPARTITION q2_1999_southeast VALUES ('FL', 'GA'),
          SUBPARTITION q2_1999_northcentral VALUES ('SD', 'WI'),
          SUBPARTITION q2_1999_southcentral VALUES ('OK', 'TX')
         ),
       PARTITION q3_1999 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-OCT-1999','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_3
         (SUBPARTITION q3_1999_northwest VALUES ('OR', 'WA'),
          SUBPARTITION q3_1999_southwest VALUES ('AZ', 'UT', 'NM'),
          SUBPARTITION q3_others VALUES (DEFAULT) TABLESPACE tbs_4
         ),
       PARTITION q4_1999 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DATE('1-JAN-2000','DD-MON-YYYY'))
          TABLESPACE tbs_4
      );
```

[source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm)

Comment: Vijayakumar Udupa, i just came also along with the DEFAULT value. I will surely give it a try and report my results. Thank you !

Comment: @Stephan Any luck with test?

Comment: Yes, that worked. I do not any performance increase in my queries though compared to the old table but this is another topic. I am facing a new problem with the partition indexes on subpartitions currently. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't think there will be any decrease in performance because of default clause. Since Oracle knows basis of partitioning, as long your queries supply data which is key for partitioning , you should be able to get results like it was before. Major contributing factor in this case would be your indexes rather than partition DEFAULT value based list partitioning.

Comment: Let me give some further information of my problem. Currently i got a table with approx. 5 million entries. 4 million entries are not that important but have to be kept in the database. Those 4 millions are "Europe" data (lets call them like that as in my questions description) . The rest 1 million data which are also the most important and i want an increase in performance are the "NOT EUROPE" , which in my case fall into the values(DEFAULT) case. I do not see any other way to include all that 1 million data (NOT EUROPE) into a user defined partition instead of the default.

Comment: As long your query has clause like 'continent =[continet name]' oracle will figure out which partition it has to pick. In fact, building an index in the combination of your (range key,list key) will improve query performance. Note: just partitioning will not help with performance directly, it helps in easy management of data. Also, oracle has feature when you can run a query directly on a partition (if you can arrive at partition name and make it part of your query somehow). This gives lot of performance benefit as I've seen in the past.

Comment: unfortunately the where clauses may not be always come together since this is a generated query from a java api that corresponds to a search function (the where clauses are the search criteria) . So i don't know if building an index on both range and state would be such a good idea. As for selecting directly on a subpartition as you mention , is something i have tried already and it does indeed increase the performance. The query cost dropped from 150.000 to only 4-5.000 . What i am not really aware yet, is if the java api i use supports the selects on subpartition.

Comment: @VijayakumarUdupa. Partitioning alone **can** in fact improve performance; Oracle can do partition pruning based on the predicate.

Comment: @BobC Thanks for pointing that. You are right, but it should not discourage us from creating index.

Comment: @VijayakumarUdupa. I am not discouraging the use of indexes as such, but it's important to understand when and where to use them. For example, why would you create an index on the partitioning key?