# Partitioning a table with one value in one partition and the rest in another partition

Tags: oracle, partitioning, ddl

For example, I have a table name Emp and it has empname, designation, salary as columns. I would like this table to have 2 partitions, like list of employees who are managers in one partition and rest(engineer, peon, clerk) in one partition.

can someone help on how to create it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you will have to use LIST based partition. Create a pertition where ROLE = MANAGER and create another partition which is default.  Here is an example which will help you.

[Exclude values from oracle partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691961/exclude-values-from-oracle-partition/41692060#41692060)

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (EMP_ID VARCHAR2(25), 
                       EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(250),
                       ROLE VARCHAR2(100)
                       )
     PARTITION BY LIST (ROLE) 
     (
     PARTITION part_managers
        VALUES ('MANAGER'),

     PARTITION part_others
        VALUES (DEFAULT)
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following URL and example:
For example, the following SQL statement splits the sales_Q4_2007 partition of the partitioned by range table sales splits into five partitions corresponding to the quarters of the next year. In this example, the partition sales_Q4_2008 implicitly becomes the high bound of the split partition.

```
ALTER TABLE sales SPLIT PARTITION sales_Q4_2007 INTO
( PARTITION sales_Q4_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION sales_Q1_2008 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2008','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION sales_Q2_2008 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2008','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION sales_Q3_2008 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2008','dd-MON-yyyy')),
  PARTITION sales_Q4_2008);
```

For the sample table customers partitioned by list, the following statement splits the partition Europe into three partitions.

```
ALTER TABLE list_customers SPLIT PARTITION Europe INTO
  (PARTITION western-europe VALUES ('GERMANY', 'FRANCE'),
   PARTITION southern-europe VALUES ('ITALY'), 
   PARTITION rest-europe);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-01C14320-0D7B-48BE-A5AD-003DDA761277.htm

You will get some idea about this.

Comment: What is your motivation for a 2 partition table?

Comment: @BobC performance reason for example. You may have one huge partition with historical data which is rarely used by any query and one small partition which is "active" and heavily queried.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. That *might* be one example; but I have rarely seen a 2 partition strategy like this work. Moreover, the "historical" partition does not appear to be the use case presented. I'm not say the OP is wrong or you cant do it, but they may be taking the wrong approach to whatever problem they have.